# 500 internal server error while deploying flask app on cpanel

Tags: flask, cpanel, internal-server-error

**getting 500 internal server error while deploying flask app on cpanel**

this is the error log =

'''2023-06-25 13:55:36.955411 [INFO] [4538] [T0] [106.213.85.212:18039#APVH_vocalcopy.com] File not found [/home/vocalcop/public_html/404.shtml]
2023-06-25 13:55:36.955391 [INFO] [4538] [T0] [106.213.85.212:18039#APVH_vocalcopy.com] Index file is not available in [/home/vocalcop/public_html/]'''